# Expand/Collapse groups in expandable recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

I am using [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view) library to implement an expandable `RecyclerView`. I have implemented it, and it works fine. But what I want is the group should only expand if I click a particular view. Right now what is happening is if I click anywhere on the `RecyclerView` item, the group expands. I have an `ImageView`, and when I click that ImageView, only then the group should expand. How can I implement this?

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java:**

```
public class GenresSongAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<SongDetailsViewHolder, OptionViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    public GenresSongAdapter(Context context, List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups) {
        super(groups);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public SongDetailsViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_song, parent, false);
        return new SongDetailsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public OptionViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_artists, parent, false);
        return new OptionViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(OptionViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {
        ArtistsModel artistsModel = (ArtistsModel) group.getItems().get(childIndex);
        holder.ArtistText.setText(artistsModel.getArtistsName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindGroupViewHolder(SongDetailsViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup songInfo) {
        holder.setSongDetails(mContext, songInfo);
    }
}
```

**SongDetailsViewHolder.java**

```
class SongDetailsViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder {
    public TextView songName;
    public TextView artistName;
    public TextView duration;
    public ImageView iv_artwork;

    public SongDetailsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        songName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.SongName);
        artistName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ArtistName);
        duration = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        iv_artwork = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_artwork);
    }

    public void setSongDetails(Context mContext, ExpandableGroup songInfo) {
        if (songInfo instanceof SongInfo) {
            songName.setText(songInfo.getTitle());
            artistName.setText(((SongInfo) songInfo).getArtistName());
            duration.setText(((SongInfo) songInfo).getSongDuration());
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(((SongInfo) songInfo).getImageURI()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).into(iv_artwork);
        }
    }
}
```

**OptionViewHolder.java**

```
class OptionViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {
    TextView ArtistText;

    public OptionViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ArtistText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ArtistText);
    }
}
```

Comment: feel free to modify ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter (whatever it is) source to fulfill your needs ... eventually ask library's author to do this

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a bit of guesswork here since I can't afford to make a test project with your setup at the moment.

You don't need to "modify" `ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter` as @Selvin is suggesting; it suffice to overwrite the class as you already did with `GenresSongAdapter`. Simply add to this class. My approach would entail two steps (but it turns out that these steps can be taken in a single method):

1. Disable the built-in expand-on-click behaviour and
2. Connect an `OnGroupClickListener` (whose `onGroupClick` callback encapsulates that behaviour) with the `ImageView`s.

We disable the `OnGroupClickListener`s of the adapter by not setting them to the view holders in the first place (as it is done in the parent class). Therefore we need to overwrite the `onCreateViewHolder()` method of the adapter and simply skip the command by which the listener is set. However, in the same method we can get a view holder, including all its members. Therefore we can attach a listener to each view holders' `ImageView`.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case ExpandableListPosition.GROUP:
            SongDetailsViewHolder sdvh = onCreateGroupViewHolder(parent, viewType);
            sdvh.iv_artwork.setOnGroupClickListener(this); 
            return sdvh;
        case ExpandableListPosition.CHILD:
            OptionViewHolder ovh = onCreateChildViewHolder(parent, viewType);
            return ovh;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("viewType is not valid");
    }
}
```

You will also have to evade the `OnClickListener`s set by the `GroupViewHolder` class, possibly by simply extending `SongDetailsViewHolder` directly from `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

This is untested code, but I am pretty sure that at least the idea is correct :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for sparing your time for this, actually I solved this by myself. I did pretty much same as you. I disabled the `OnGroupClickListeners ` and add this `toggle(layout)` to my viewHolder.